# problem with "if condition" in r - assigning values error

Tags: r

I'm doing if condition and I want to match values from 2 different columns and of they match it has to assign value to another column. when I write the statement

```
for (l in 1:k) { 
  for(i in 1:n) { 
    if(y_related[i,2]==con_f[l]) {
      y_out[l]=y_related[i,1] 
    }
  }
}
```

then it doesn't work! but if I replaced the con_f with it's numerical value say 0.004 then it works. but I wanted to run it automatically as I don't want to write the numerical value every time!!

detailed example:

```
y_related=matrix(NA,1000,2) 
y_related[,1]=rnorm(1000,5,10) 
y_related[,2]=rank(y_related[,1])/1000 
con_f=matrix(NA,250,1) 
for(x in 1:250) { 
  con_f[x]=(1-((x-1)/250))
}
y_out=matrix(NA,250,1) 
for (l in 1:250) { 
  for(i in 1:1000) { 
    if(y_related[i,2]==con_f[l]) {
      y_out[l]=y_related[i,1]
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to your issue to make it reproducible.

Comment: y_related=matrix(NA,1000,2)    
y_related[,1]=rnorm(1000,5,10)
y_related[,2]=rank(y_related[,1])/1000
con_f=matrix(NA,250,1)
for(x in 1:250){con_f[x]=(1-((x-1)/250))}
y_out=matrix(NA,250,1)
for (l in 1:250){for(i in 1:1000){if(y_related[i,2]==con_f[l]){y_out[l]=y_related[i,1]}}}

Comment: @slava-kohut there is always problem at l=17 and 18 for example even though that they have match in y_related[,2]

Comment: please modify your initial post

Comment: I don't get any error running your detailed example, how does it "not work" ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the function [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/merge)

```
# Turn them in to data frames, and rename to sensible names
y_related_df <- as.data.frame(y_related)
names(y_related_df) <- c("value", "variable")
con_f_df <- as.data.frame(con_f)
names(con_f_df) <- c("variable")

# merge allows you to join on a vector of variables, and then move the data from
# y in to x as we've done a left join (all.x=TRUE)
output <- merge(x=con_f_df, y=y_related_df, by="variable", all.x=TRUE)
output
```

If you're not familiar with different types of joins, then have a look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

`merge` is very very useful, I use it all the time